# Conservation of momentum on a zero-friction floor

Tags: momentum

If we have an object of a certain mass that's moving on a non-friction floor with a certain velocity `v`, and we suppose that at some point we take off half of the mass of that object, does the velocity increase to `2v` - since the system is closed so the momentum  is supposed to be conserved - , and if it does, how so? regarding the fact that the net force is zero and an increase in velocity means a presence of non zero force!

Comment: How do you "take off half of the mass of that object"? What happens to the mass you took away? It can't simply vanish into nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object is moving with velocity $v$ and you slice it in half perpendicular to the plane of the floor, each piece moves with velocity $v$ and thus horizontal momentum is conserved since the force is perpendicular to the floor. If there’s a spontaneous breakup such as an explosion, then the final momenta of the pieces depends on the force that each piece exerts on the other. If there’s a third object moving in a horizontal plane that hits the object, splitting it in half, then the total horizontal momentum of the pieces will definitely not be $2v$, since now there is an external force on the system in consideration (I.e. the original object that breaks into two).

TL; DR: How you break the object in half matters.

Comment: Also note that given an internal explosion, as non-intuitive as it seems, the total momenta of all the pieces added together equals the momentum of the object before it exploded, even though each individual piece has its own momentum.

Comment: @David White Yes, that is a good point. Shrapnel from an exploding bomb have a total momentum of zero, provided the bomb was still before it exploded, because the force of the explosion is internal to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is only conserved for a closed system.  If you remove half the mass of a system, it is not closed.